A different choice of variable name makes the solution different?
I was trying to solve a system of polynomial equations, which contains three equations and 6 variables $a_0,a_1,a_2,b_0,b_1,b_2$. However, what I discover is that if i swap the variable name $a_0,a_1,a_2$ with $b_0,b_1,b_2$, Maple gives me a totally different solution set. Only the solution before swapping the variable names is the solution I look for. How could that be? Here is the code
infolevel[solve] := 3
with(PolynomialTools)
N := (-t^2 - 1)*u^2 - 2*(t^2 + 1)^2*u + 2*t
B := u^2*b[2] + u*b[1] + b[0]
A := u^2*a[2] + u*a[1] + a[0]
i := CoefficientList(B*diff(A, u) - A*diff(B, u), u)
j := CoefficientList(N, u)
solve({i[1] = j[1], i[2] = j[2], i[3] = j[3]}, {a[0], a[1], a[2], b[0], b[1], b[2]})
B1 := u^2*a[2] + u*a[1] + a[0]
A1 := u^2*b[2] + u*b[1] + b[0]
List3 := CoefficientList(N, u);
List4 := CoefficientList(B1*diff(A1, u) - A1*diff(B1, u), u);
solve({List3[1] = List4[1], List3[2] = List4[2], List3[3] = List4[3]}, {a[0], a[1], a[2], b[0], b[1], b[2]});

the system before swapping the variable name:
$$
-a_0b_1 + a_1b_0=2t
$$
$$
-2a_0b_2 + 2a_2b_0=-2(t^2 + 1)^2
$$
$$
-a_1b_2 + a_2b_1=-t^2 - 1
$$
And $t$ is treated as constant. The solution reads for:
$$
a_0=a_0, a_1 = \frac{2t}{b_0}, a_2 = -\frac{2t^5 - t^2a_0b_0 + 4t^3 - a_0b_0 + 2t}{2tb_0},b_0 = b_0, b_1 = 0, b_2 = \frac{b_0(t^2 + 1)}{2t}
$$
After swapping, the system becomes:
$$
a_0b_1 - a_1b_0=2t
$$
$$
2a_0b_2 - 2a_2b_0=-2(t^2 + 1)^2
$$
$$
a_1b_2 - a_2b_1=-t^2 - 1
$$
And the solution Maple gives:
$$
a_0 = \frac{2t}{b_1},a_1 = \frac{2(t^2 - a_2b_1 + 1)t}{(t^4 + 2t^2 + 1)b_1}, a_2 = a_2, b_0 = 0, b_1 = b_1, b_2 = -\frac{(t^4 + 2t^2 + 1)b_1}{2t}
$$

If you write down the system of equation using Mathjax it makes easier to understand what the issue is

I have added the latex for equations system

Can you show us the two solutions you get?

I have added solutions Maple gives for both system

Have you tried changing both pairs of {...} in the last line by [...]?

I have tried changing {} to [] but does not work

Or maybe, does this two are equivalent?

Interesting, so I don't know Maple to check your code for bugs but assuming it's correct, the following has probably happened. For some reason (no clue why) you get different families of solutions. This is a non-linear system so they are tough in general to analyze. I doubt the solutions are equivalent, in the first case you got b_1 = 0 but in the second b_0 = 0. I don't know how Maple solves them but I guess somehow picks one infinite family of solutions, and in the second case picked another. Check for t = 1 to maybe get some insight.

First, swapping the $a_i$ and $b_i$ changes the sign of the LH side of each of your equations, so the new system is not the same as the old, and will have a different solution. However, it should just have some different signs in the final equation. But, second, your first system expresses the solution set as equations in $a_0, b_0$, while the second set expresses it as equations in $a_2, b_1$. These are independent solutions, since the first solution assumes $b_0 \ne 0$ and results in $b_1 = 0$, while the second solution assumes $b_1 \ne 0$ and results in $b_0 = 0$.

I agree that these are independent sets of solutions. Could we find all the independent sets of solutions by changing the Maple 'solve' command? I mean, if there are finite sets of solutions.

This is a question I am still investigating. I found it surprising Maple solved for four of the variables in terms of the other two, when it had only three equations to solve. I do not see how it managed this trick. It is something that does not happen in linear equations.

Your three equations can be recast as
$$\begin{align}a_0b_1 - a_1b_0&=c_2\\a_2b_0-a_0b_2&=c_1\\a_1b_2-a_2b_1&=c_0\end{align}$$
where the $c_i$ are constants. In your case, these constants hold a certain relation to each other:
$$\begin{align}c_0 &= -(t^2+1)\\c_1 &= (t^2+1)^2\\c_2 &= 2t\end{align}$$
(I multiplied the middle equation through by $-\frac12$, which puts it in a consistent ordering with the other two). Note that $c_0 \ne 0, c_1 \ne 0$ for any real value of $t$.
If we multiply the first equation by $b_2$, the second by $b_1$, and the third by $b_0$, then add them all up, we get $$0 = b_0c_0 + b_1c_1 + b_2c_2$$ and similarly $$0 = a_0c_0 + a_1c_1 + a_2c_2$$
We may eliminate $a_0,b_0$ from the equations: $$\begin{align}a_0 &= \frac{a_1c_1 + a_2c_2}{-c_0} = a_1(t^2+1) +a_2\frac{2t}{(t^2+1)} \\b_0 &= \frac{b_1c_1 + b_2c_2}{-c_0}= b_1(t^2+1) +b_2\frac{2t}{(t^2+1)}\end{align}$$ and the first and second equations reduce to the third:
$$a_1b_2 - a_2b_1=c_0$$
Here we have two cases:

$b_1 = b_2 = 0$: $a_1, a_2$ vary freely. Note that also $b_0 = 0$ in this case.
$a_1, b_1, b_2$ vary freely except $b_1 \ne 0$, and $a_2 = \frac{a_1b_2 -c_0}{b_1}$.

In your case, the solutions are specifically:

$a_1, a_2$ vary freely. $$b_0 = b_1 = b_2 = 0\\a_0 = a_1(t^2+1) +a_2\frac{2t}{(t^2+1)}$$
$a_1, b_1, b_2$ vary freely except $b_1 \ne 0$.
$$\begin{align}a_2 &= \frac{a_1b_2 - 2t}{b_1}\\a_0 &= a_1(t^2+1) +a_2\frac{2t}{(t^2+1)}\\b_0 &= b_1(t^2+1) +b_2\frac{2t}{(t^2+1)}\end{align}$$

It appears that when Maple solved it, it only looked at cases where one of the $b_i = 0$, and thus missed most of the solutions for the second case. And of course, it chose different sets of free variables, so some conversion is needed to rewrite the formulas in terms of other variables instead.
Why Maple demanded that one of the variables be $0$ is something I cannot answer.
